# Motivation of the murderer in Season 3

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bridge

Having watched season three of TV series *Bron* aka *Broen* aka *The Bridge*, I am not able to comprehend why Emil Larsson killed his first victim, Helle Anker.

She was a bearer of sperm of Freddie Holst (Larsson's father) but as far as I know she had not violated or harmed Emil. So there was no reason for revenge.

Comment: We just finished watching The Bridge, Season 3, last night, and were left with the same question. What was the motivation for Emil Larsson to kill Helle Anker? It has something to do with Morten, but what, exactly? I don't recall that it was ever suggested that Villy was NOT Morten's father...what did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Reddit post attempts to explain it](https://www.reddit.com/r/bronbroen/comments/3xkjld/spoiler_alert_s03_e10_whats_the_connection_between/cy6gd1s):

> From what I understood, Helle Anker used Freddie Holst's sperm to have
>   a kid (Martin Anker) but destroyed all evidence at the clinic she had
>   set up. She then she must've told Martin to look up the code at the
>   clinic to find his real Dad and when he did he would've seen he had a
>   brother (Emil) and that must've been how they met and I guess how Emil
>   found out about his real parents.
>
> So **his 'creators' were his Dad and the woman responsible for setting
>   up the clinic.**

[This Guardian commenter has a similar explanation](https://discussion.theguardian.com/comment-permalink/65454344):

> For anyone wondering about the whole Emil/Morten relationship and why
>   Helle Anker was referred to as Emil's "creator", I believe it stems
>   from the fact that **Helle Anker set up the fertility clinic**. She used
>   Freddie Holst's sperm for herself so that she could give birth to
>   Morten, and later in life gave Morten some more information about his
>   beginnings. As Helle ran the fertility clinic, she was able to give
>   Morten the infamous code for Freddie Holst's sperm donation to
>   Anne-Marie Larsson. This enabled Morten to find his half brother, Emil
>   Larsson. This backfired spectacularly. **Emil resents the fact he was
>   ever born and takes revenge on Freddie (his sperm donor father) and
>   Helle Anker ("his creator" i.e. The lady who ran the fertility clinic
>   in which Emil was artificially inseminated).** Emil was none the wiser
>   about his beginnings until Morten contacted him.